# Counting each DIFFERENT character in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python and coding and I'm trying to write a code that counts the number of times each different character comes out in a text file while disregarding the case of the characters.

What I have so far is

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
       'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

prompt = "Enter filename: "

titles = "char       count\n----       -----"

itemfmt = "{0:5s}{1:10d}"

totalfmt = "total{0:10d}"

whiteSpace = {' ':'space', '\t':'tab', '\n':'nline', '\r':'crtn'}

filename = input(prompt)

fname = filename
numberCharacters = 0
fname = open(filename, 'r')

for line in fname:
    linecount +=1
    word = line.split()
    word += words
for word in words:
    for char in word:
        numberCharacters += 1
return numberCharacters
```

Somethings seems wrong about this. Is there a more efficient way to do my desired task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
frequency_per_character = Counter(open(filename).read().lower())
```

Then you can display them as you wish.

Comment: I've never used the Counter. How would I implement it into my code?

Comment: Just like I wrote it. `Counter` is an iterable that you can access just like it was a `dict`. `frequency_per_character['a']`, or `for k, v in frequency_per_character.iteritems():`, or similar should all work.

Answer (score 0):

You over-complicating it, you can just convert your file content to a set in order to eliminate duplicated characters:

```py
number_diff_value = len(set(open("file_path").read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use the `str` methods such as [`isAlpha`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha:)

```
chars = {}
for l in open('filename', 'rU'):
    for c in l:
         if not c.isalpha(): continue
         chars[c] = chars.get(c, 0) + 1
```

And then use the `chars` `dict` to write the final histogram.